# how can i check if the field is in the $_POST[''] by init() function in prestashop?

Tags: prestashop

how can i check  if the field is in the $_POST[''] by init() function in prestashop ?

I have the following code in my controller:

```
$insertData = array(
     'app_id'  => 1,
     'app_name'  => 'google plus',
     'status'   => 0,
     'title'  => 'google title'
  );
```

Db::getInstance()->insert("your table name", $insertData);

and in my view i have the following button :

```
<button name="avant_btn" id="avant_btn" type="button" style="width: 65px; height: 65px;" >Avant</button>
```

to perform the add operation when click to button it must add POST to the button (just send some form)
then in the init() function check if the field is in the $_POST['']

so did some search of how to check field in init function without results , hope help and thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can get that value by Tools::getValue('avant_btn'); and this is easy to got the value.

Comment: but **Tools::getValue()** returns values for both POST and GET requests... Needed *field is in the $_POST['']* ...